# Will ultrapasterized milk curdle?

Tags: baking, milk, vinegar, pancakes

Normally (e.g. [here](https://1000.menu/cooking/17450-oladi-na-kefire-bez-drojjei-pyshnye)) the recipe for [oladyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oladyi) (thick palm-sized pancakes) requires [kefir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kefir), a fermented milk drink similar to a thin yoghurt or ayran.

There is one [well-tested recipe](https://www.iamcook.ru/showrecipe/14287) that uses milk with lemon juice (or vinegar) instead: to begin, one has to heat the milk up to 36C-38C (body temperature), add 1tbsp of vinegar, let it rest for 15 min. I am guessing this is done to curdle the milk, right? Will this process work as expected if the milk is [ultrapasterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-temperature_processing)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not curdle as well as regular pasteurized milk will, but probably good enough for the recipe you're making.

Ultrapasteurized milk, because of its "cooked" nature, doesn't form curds as well as other kinds of milk.  Particularly, you [cannot make cheese from it](https://cheesemaking.com/blogs/fun-along-the-whey/problems-with-ultra-pasteurized-milk) because the proteins have been changed by the high-heat sterilization.  They [have been denatured](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11570017/).

However, this recipe does not seem to depend very much on the texture of the curds made during the curdling process in the first two steps.  If you were draining the whey, I'd say not to use UHT milk, but in this case everything is still mixed in.  At worst, the pancakes would have slightly inferior texture to those made with regular milk.

Comment: Yes, it was pretty much as you say, it worked out, but the texture was inferior.

Comment: Yulia: if my answer is correct, please select it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will curdle. It is a chemical process where the proteins clump, the ultrapasteurization doesn't prevent it.

The other question is, do you need to do that at all. The whole reason to use cultured milk products in this kind of pancake-like recipes is that you need acid to react with the baking soda. So you can simply throw everything together, without premixing the vinegar and the milk. It will work quite the same way (unless you happen to pour it such that the vinegar and baking soda react too early). If you insist on mixing the milk and vinegar first, it would have worked if it didn't curdle (or it will work if you pick something which won't curdle, such as almond milk). Or you can simply switch to a recipe with baking powder and use whichever liquid (dairy or not) you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for guessing what my question was in spite of me using the incorrect word. 
I guess I will try the heating method first, out of an abundance of caution, then compare it to the simplified method you suggest!

Comment: Note the taste of curdled milk, vs taste of kefir are completely different, in particular kefir is a well-liked refreshing drink often served alongside fatty foods, while I don't know anyone who'd find taste of curdled milk agreeable.

Comment: @SF. it is not such a big factor here. First, milk which has been curdled intentionally with vinegar is also consumed (usually after pressing, which makes it into paneer or related cheeses). Second, the second reason why these recipes are that way is that, in the days before refrigeration and food safety concerns, they were a welcome way of using up milk that has soured and curdled on its own.

Comment: Rumtscho: UHT milk does not curdle properly -- the proteins *have* been changed.  See my answer, below.

Comment: @FuzzyChef yes, they have been changed somewhat. The proteins have many states though - and those in UHT milk are still capable of linking into a yogurt, or a curd. You'll see that the UHT milk in the post you link in your answer has also curdled, it is just not the exact texture needed for cheese.